# Laravel not sending email and not giving errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel is not sending emails; I set it up to use the mail driver and put in the right code, but it seems not to work at all. Besides not working, it doesn't even give me an error!

Here is my configuration:

```
return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail"
|
*/

'driver' => 'mail',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Postmark mail service, which will provide reliable delivery.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to delivery e-mails to
| users of your application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Postmark e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

);
```

Here is my PHP code  for sending email:

```
$data["mail_message"] = "Hello!";

    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message
            ->to('me@mydomain.com')
            ->from('info@otherdomain.com')
            ->subject('TEST');
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use SMTP, Sendmail or Mail?

Comment: I'm trying to use Mail

Comment: Having same issue. Using 'mail' driver. Very frustrating.

Comment: Possible ".env" overrides "config/mail.php", please check: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980979/laravel-not-sending-email-and-not-giving-errors/34998699#34998699)

Comment: The same happened to me, but I could use try-catch to figure out what happened.

Comment: Checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783476/laravel-5-7-no-verification-email-sent). It worked for me.

Comment: Can you check this [tutorial](https://devnote.in/how-to-send-email-in-laravel-with-example/)?

Answer (score 21):

You can check general E-Mail delivery by typing:

```
php artisan tinker

Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin (
    new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger(false))
);
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
Mail::raw('Testmail', function ($message) use($to) {  
    $message->to($to)->subject('Testmail'); 
});
```

And you will get even the output of the SMTP dialog.

> Make sure to replace `$to` with your mail address to check if it arrives.

*EDIT* If this works and you still have problems with email delivery, you might have a queuing issue.

Comment: Very useful snippet thanks.  Unfortunately only confused me more as this worked perfectly but mail called by the queue worker hangs for one minute

Comment: Good point - it's only for testing mail delivery when queuing is not involved :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin` and `Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger` do not exist in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 19):

In my scenario email was being queued so that is why I got no output. I had forgotten I set email to [queue by default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#queueing-mail). I looked in the Jobs table I saw all my messages waiting in there. I ran `php artisan queue:work` to get the queue running/sending them.

Comment: I didn't add the queue to supervisor so it didn't start after a server restart, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 18):

First and foremost, go to the app/config/mail.php and change the driver to “mail”. Also put the host as blank.

Comment: If you have not purchased smtp then change settings for mail as above.

Comment: I tried various settings and it doesn't work, in fact their documentation says "mail" setting is removed. And unfortunately "sendmail" doesn't just send mail from your server using sendmail command, it appears smtp is the only way it can send anymore: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/866

Comment: Anyone trying this method, do not forget to clear the cache, 
`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 6):

**The Fix That Worked For Me**

1. In your `.env` file change `APP_URL=127.0.01` to `APP_URL=http://localhost`
2. Set your SMTP details correctly, and do `config:cache`, then restart server.

After that my mail started sending!

**How I Arrived At That Fix**

I had previously set my SMTP details up correctly, but even after doing config:cache config:clear and restarting my server, the emails were not sending. After that I compared it to my working Laravel App, and the only difference was the 127.0.0.1 -> http://localhost, so I changed that as a last ditch attempt, and it worked.

Comment: UPDATE: 2nd July 2018: I received all mails eventually, so not sure if there was just a delay, or they are stored up and keep trying to resend inside Laravel until the settings are correct.

Comment: `config:cache` did it for me!

Answer (score 6):

A solution for notifications not sent via 'mail'

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#customizing-the-recipient

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Route notifications for the mail channel.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return string
     */
    public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
    {
        return $this->email_address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the laravel bug

Answer (score 5):

Go to .env file and set

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

Or you can set driver from the config files. Go to file
Laravel 4 : app/config/mail.php
Laravel 5 : config/mail.php
and set

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
```

You may use SMTP. Hope It will help.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little more explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Ok @TarynEast i will ensure that i should provide more description for better understanding from next time.
Thanks

Comment: You can still provide more information this time - you just need to edit it :)

Comment: Thanks to remember me. I have just change the description. Please check.

Answer (score 5):

It could be because you have a ".env" file, in the Laravel project root, with mail server configuration like this:

```
...
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

It seems the ".env" file just overrides "config/mail.php" file. You can just remove same lines from the ".env" file for use "config/mail.php" configuration options.

Comment: No, the `config/mail.php` doesn't need to be touched because of `.env` file. Better is to put it's name (`.env`) in `.gitignore` file and distribute the `.env.example` to allow local changes to `.env`.

Comment: @Roland not "doesn't need".. It's strictly related to your solution. In most cases with different deployment environment you really need a .env file, but in case if it's local / local=production environment you can use mail.php. But of course it's preferred to use more robust solution in the .env.

Comment: Or should I better write "shouldn't be touched" as it is mostly committed (and only in rare cases like yours maybe it is touched)?

Answer (score 3):

Configuration file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=abc@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Then run the [`make:mail`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#generating-mailables) command:

```
public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->view('mail['variable'=>$request->message])->to($request->to);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('send', 'mailController@send');
Route::get('email', 'mailController@email');
```

Controller:

```
public function send()
{
    Mail::send(new name());
}

public function email()
{
    return view('email');
}
```

View:

```
<body><br><h1>Send Mail</h1><form method="post" action="send">to:<input type="text" name="to">message: <input type="text"  name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></input><input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"></form></body>
```

Mail:

```
<body><h1>Welcome, to this mail system, </h1>{!! $variable !!}</body>
```

Thing to remember: The `message` variable is a build-in variable and will generate error so use any other variable instead of `message`.

More details:

- https://codingexpertise.blogspot.com/2018/12/how-to-send-mail-in-laravel.html
- https://codingexpertise.blogspot.com/2018/11/laravel-new.html

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue ! and then i noticed that my boss made changes to config/mail.php.
Here is what you need :

set Mail variables in your .env file :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

in config/mail.php, make sure you have `something => env('ENV_VARIABLE_NAME', 'default_value')`

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
```

If you have ssl issues, add to config/mail.php :

```
'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]
```

Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Bluehost shared hosting. I have contacted their support 3 times and they said that there is no problem on their side, but I think that it is something in the hosting settings, because I send the emails from Bulgarian hosting SMTP without any problems.

But let me tell you what solves this problem with Bluehost:

I added this to my .env file:

```
MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN="yourdomain.com"
```

Replace yourdomain.com with your domain.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work. If you're using mailgun, add this information below to your `.env` file

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=your.mailgundomain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-yourmailgunkey
```

and then run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 6, if verification email is not send anymore:

in user.php add

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

and

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

and in routes/web.php

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstle go to your project root on cmd and run this cmd -

```
php artisan route:cache (clear your routes cache)
php artisan cache:clear (clear your application cache)
php artisan config:cache (clear your config cache)
php artisan view:clear (clear your view (blade) cache)
```

Go to .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YourUserName
MAIL_PASSWORD=YourPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Go to project root and use this cmd

```
php artisan make:mail WelcomeUserVerifyMail
```

after that goto App\mail\WelcomeUserVerifyMail
add these line -

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
public $mailData;
public function __construct(array $mailData)
{
  $this->mailData = $mailData;
}
public function build()
{
return $this->from(env('MAIL_FROM'))->subject('Test')->view('email-template.email'); //view load
}
```

In your controller where you use mail functionality -

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\WelcomeUserVerifyMail;

// Send Verify email
$mailData = ['name' => "Shubham Gupta", 'verifyButtonUrl' => $verifyButtonUrl];
Mail::to('shubham@yopmail.com')->send(new WelcomeUserVerifyMail($mailData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Mail::to** instead of Mail::send

Here's an example. In this one, we send an order info mail.

1. Apply this command (your project's root folder)

```
php artisan make:mail OrderInfoMail
```

2. Add OrderInfoMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;

class OrderInfoMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this
            ->subject('Order Confirmation')
            ->from('noreply@app.xxx.co.uk', 'XXX Portal')
            ->view('orders.templates.order-form')
            ->with([
                'name' => $this->data->name,
                // more info..
            ]);

        $this->withSymfonyMessage(function (Email $message) {
            $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader(
                'X-Mailer', 'PHP/' . phpversion()
            );
        });

        return $this;
    }
}
```

3. Add order-form.blade.php (under orders/templates folder)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Order Info</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding: 25px;">
        <p><strong>Date:</strong> {{date('d.m.Y')}}</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 5px; padding: 25px;">
        <p>
            Dear {{$name}}, thank you for choosing us. Your order will be produced and installed on the date you agreed with your seller...
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- more info -->
</body>
</html>
```

4. Call it with relevant data

```
$email = 'a@b.com'; // pls change
$name = 'ab';// pls change

$data = new \stdClass();
$data->name = $name;
// more info..

Mail::to($email)->send(new \App\Mail\OrderInfoMail($data));
```

Read more on https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/mail

Answer (score 0):

I spent several days on this issue. For me (Laravel 9) the solution was to set `local_domain` in `mail.php` in `smtp` section, or `MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN` in `.env` file, it should not be `null` because by default `127.0.0.1` was set and it didn't work for me:

```
   'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mail.example.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', 'example.org')
        ],
```

Also if you use SSL/TLS encryption (465 port in my case), `'encryption'` value should be `'ssl'`, not `'tls'`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and this is what resolved it for me.

I used tinker and ran the mail code and got an error saying that port 465 timed out. So, I went into my firewall and added unblocked the outgoing port for 465 and restarted the firewall.

```
// add the port
sudo ufw allow out 465
// restart firewall
sudo ufw enable
// check the status
sudo ufw status
```

After doing this the error persisted. I then changed the encryption type in my .env file from MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls to MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

Now mail is being sent without issue.

Answer (score -1):

Change the driver in your config file to 'smtp' from 'mail'. I guess that should work.

Comment: That didn't work, i tried smtp with gmail and it sends but it sends with the gmail account which isn't what i want, i wanted the sender to bear an email from my domain like so, info@mydomain.com.

Comment: Can the smtp username in the config file be empty? I don't have experience with mailgun, but I use mandrill. In this case, the username is the username of the mandrill account. Same with password as well. Password is not the password of the account but the API key

Answer (score -1):

Not a technical answer but it fixed my issue.

If your using GMAIL to check the incoming mail just make sure you check your SPAM folder.

Answer (score -1):

I got same problem.

Mail was no sending because I didn't set the recipient for email.

Do not forget to set it.

```
$mail->to('example@example.com');
```