# Laravel 5.7 No Verification Email sent

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification

When I register a user, or click *'click here to request another'*, no verification mail is sent, although it answers with *'A fresh verification link has been sent to your email address. '* . I checked my `.env` and `config/mail.php` file and successfully tested them with tinker and `Mail::Send(...)`. I also followed the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification) and tried some solutions, which were discussed here on StackOverflow.

- My `User` extends Authenticatable, implements MustVerifyEmail and uses Notifiable
- My 'RegisterController' explicitly calls `$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification()` in the `create function`
- Added `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);` to web.php

I assume, that there is something wrong with the standard `sendEmailVerificationNotification` implementation, but I am too new to Laravel to figure out what's the problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In **web.php**, add this parameter for `auth routes`.............
// for email verification.
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Comment: Have you configured the Queue system? look here for notifications: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications

Comment: @InzamamIdrees Yes, I got this already.

Comment: @dparoli This seems important, if you want to manually send mails in combination with notifying. But is it relevant for the standard Auth implementation? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake:

I swapped out the `User` with my own user class. The column name of the mail address is **mail_address**, which differs from the default column name. Therefore I added this override to my `User`:

`public function routeNotificationForMail($notification)
    {
        return $this->email_address;
    }`